# Slow Query Log Examination - Inexplicably slow query

Tags: mysql, mysql-slow-query-log

I have something that a slow query log has spit out but not sure what it means. I googled around but found nothing and it does not seem like the log itself gave me anything to go on. It sends no rows and examines nothing. Can someone shine some light on what the following lines from the log might mean?

```
# Time: 2020-08-01T07:30:06.086234Z
# User@Host: user[user] @ [0.0.0.0] Id: 2348878
# Query_time: 9.379636 Lock_time: 0.000000 Rows_sent: 0 Rows_examined: 0
SET timestamp=1596267006;
select code from Version where panel = '1254';
```

I removed the username and IP for obvious reasons. Thank you in advance for any assistance. If I am being dumb, sorry for the noob question.

Comment: this select query needed 9 seconds tocomplete, what ios very slow, so you should chekc if you have a INDEX on panel

Comment: so something like index fragmentation?

Comment: this actually hard to tell, you could have there a spike in another program, which slowed it down and it didn't give any answer, a indexed column should give this answer quite quick, so the mention of checking the index

Comment: ah I c, its just to broad but you are giving me a place to start looking I appreciate that thank you!

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE Version`.  (You are right to be puzzled by the timing.)